# How can I solve the Kotlin Version Error in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, android-studio

The current Kotlin version is 1.9.22. I updated '' with '1.9.22', but I'm still encountering the same error even after updating.

`android>build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.22'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                     │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then │
│ update C:\Users\karth\Desktop\karthik\android\build.gradle:                     │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                    │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotline **1.9.10**

Released: August 23, 2023

For Android Studio Giraffe and Hedgehog, the Kotlin plugin 1.9.10 will be delivered with upcoming Android Studios updates.

you can check on this link: `https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details`